# WSGI middleware and app factories

Tags: python-2.7, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi, middleware

I am trying to setup middlewares on my server for python so that subdirectories of blueprints can be seen by the apache2 on the server and served under a url like **example.com/myapplicationsubfolder/routedblueprintfunction**

my **__init__.py** inside /users/ folder looks like this:

```
class WebFactionMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/myapplicationsubfolder'
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


from index import application
application.wsgi_app = WebFactionMiddleware(application.wsgi_app)
```

After I made my app factory, I couldn't use this anymore:

```
from app import app
app.wsgi_app = WebFactionMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

And I am trying to get the flask app from index.py

**Index.py** is like this:

```
from app import create_app
application = create_app()
application.run()
```

**app.py** like this:

```
def configure_errors(app):
  @app.errorhandler(500)
  def internal_server_error(error):
      return render_template('500.html'), 500

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')

    from users.views import b_users
    db.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(b_users)
    configure_errors(app)

    return app
```

If anyone has a link to a large blueprinted-appfactory-implemented source code that uses WSGI middlewares for subdirectories for a python Flask website, it would be of great help.

I'm having some serious circular import problems or subdirectory init.py issues.

```
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/somefolder/webapps/applicationsubfolder/htdocs/index.py", line 8, in <module>
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from app import create_app
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/somefolder/webapps/applicationsubfolder/htdocs/app.py", line 5, in <module>
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from users.views import b_users
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/somefolder/webapps/applicationsubfolder/htdocs/users/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from index import application
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/somefolder/webapps/applicationsubfolder/htdocs/index.py", line 8, in <module>
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from app import create_app
[Sat Nov 24 05:32:59 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: cannot import name create_app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure of your requirement. Let me try though.

1. If you want to prefix blueprint folder name before the view function url, do this:

   app.register_blueprint(b_users, url_prefix='/folder_name')

   Url will be `localhost/folder_name/url`
2. Move this inside create_app method.

   ```
   app.wsgi_app = WebFactionMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
   ```

Comment: hmm I'll give that a shot next time, but this time I simply chose to remove the middleware altogether, it's nasty stuff. And I chose to just use http://www.domain.com/ instead of domain.com/subfolder/